# Как правильно разворачивать Asp .Net Core приложение на Linux?

Tags: c#, asp.net

если обращаюсь к приложению через localhost, то все в порядке, а если обращаюсь из вне получаю то что на скриншотe. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот конфиг приложения 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но когда обращаюсь из консоли к нему (типа curl localhost:5000) все в порядке

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: Где учат делает скриншоты на телефон?
Вот официальные гайды [как развернуть сайт на линуксе](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в неправильной настройке Nginx, он был насроен на , а приложение запускалось на http://localhost:5000. 
Только и всего)